# How to filter a string variable for values starting with a letter

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

I have a messy character variable like:

```
df<-c("_oun_", "0000ff", "03815", "?3jhdb", "test", "1,000", "1.000")
```

and I would like to filter out all values that are not words. I thought a start would be to filter out all values not starting with a character.

How can I do this with `tidyverse`? For the above mentioned example, the desired output would be `test`.

Comment: What would be the desired output? only test?

Comment: yes you are right. I will add this

Comment: Or you could also try `df[str_detect(df, '^[A-Za-z]+')]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some options with `stringr`. The regex finds anything that starts `^` with a letter `[:alpha:]` (upper or lower case) and is followed by any number `+` of letters.

This prints the values directly without the need to manually subset the data:

```
str_subset(df, "^[:alpha:]+")
[1] "test"
```

With manual subsetting:

```
df[str_detect(df, "^[:alpha:]+")]
[1] "test"
```

or

```
df[str_which(df, "^[:alpha:]+")]
[1] "test"
```

Keeps the vector structure intact:

```
str_extract(df, "^[:alpha:]+")
[1] NA     NA     NA     NA     "test" NA     NA
```

Comment: The key point being that `^` is the marker for the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 2):

If you want words that are actual english words, you could use the `words` package as a dictionary look-up:

```r
df<-c("_oun_", "0000ff", "03815", "?3jhdb", "test", "1,000", "1.000")

df[df %in% words::words$word]
#> [1] "test"
```